# JavaScript: Failed to change a div's background color when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I want to change a div's background color when the button is clicked and change it back clicked again, but I can't get it through...some help please...thanks!

```
window.onload = function (){
    var oBtn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
    var oDiv = document.getElementById('div1');
    var sDivClass = oDiv.className;

    oBtn1.onclick = function() {
        if (sDivClass == 'div1') {
            sDivClass = 'toGreen';
            oBtn1.value = 'to Red';
        } else {
            sDivClass = 'div1';
            oBtn1.value = 'To Green';
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div1" id="div1"></div>
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="To Green" />
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.toGreen {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only changing the value of the local variable, not the class associated with the DIV.  Try

```
 oBtn1.onclick = function() {
                    if (oDiv.className === 'div1') {
                        oDiv.className = 'toGreen';
                        oBtn1.value = 'to Red';

                    } else {
                        oDiv.className = 'div1';
                        oBtn1.value = 'To Green';
                    }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that too when I replaced it with oDiv.className, but I thought I used var sDivClass = oDiv.className which already declares a global variable? Sorry really novice here.

Comment: @Serene `var sDivClass = oDiv.className;` is just a copy of the className string, changing it later doesn't effect actual div className property, it's just value, not reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code. The first is that you don't actually assign new class name to the div. And the second is that if the class name is `div1` new class should become `div1 toGreen`, not just `toGreen` (do that div still had base styles from `div1` class). Fixed code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var oBtn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
    var oDiv = document.getElementById('div1');

    oBtn1.onclick = function () {
        if (oDiv.className == 'div1') {
            oDiv.className = 'div1 toGreen';
            oBtn1.value = 'to Red';
        } else {
            oDiv.className = 'div1';
            oBtn1.value = 'To Green';
        }
    }
};
```